# Approve/ Reject Method Not Work In asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I made a method for approving or rejecting registration requests from the user registration form.

When users submit a form, the request becomes pending and then admin has the authority to reject or approve the request; but my method does not work properly, because nothing happen.

The application just refresh the page when I click on the reject or approve button.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? Code snippets follow.

**This is the approval controller**

```
   public class ApprovedRegistrationController :BaseAdminController
{
    // GET: Admin/ApproveRegistration
    public ActionResult Index(string Status)
    { ViewBag.Status = (Status == null ? "P" : Status);
        if (Status == null)
        { var register = objBs.registerBs.GetALL().Where(x => x.Approved == "P").ToList();
            return View(register); }
        else
        { var register = objBs.registerBs.GetALL().Where(x => x.Approved == Status).ToList();
            return View(register); }}

    public ActionResult Approve(int id)
    {   try
        { var myRegistration = objBs.registerBs.GetByID(id);
            myRegistration.Approved = "A";
            objBs.registerBs.Update(myRegistration);
            TempData["Msg"] = "Approved Successfully";
            return RedirectToAction("Index"); }
        catch (Exception e1)
        { TempData["Msg"] = "Approved Failed: " + e1.Message;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");}}

    public ActionResult Reject(int id)
    {try
        { var myRegistration = objBs.registerBs.GetByID(id);
            myRegistration.Approved = "R";
            objBs.registerBs.Update(myRegistration);
            TempData["Msg"] = "Rejected Successfully";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");}
        catch (Exception e1)
        { TempData["Msg"] = "Rejection Failed: " + e1.Message;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");}}}
```

**Registration Approval or rejection view**

```
    @model IEnumerable<XtechWebsite.Models.Registration>

    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";}

   <h2>Index</h2>

   <script>
      function ConfirmApprove() {

        return confirm('Are u sure to accept it?');

    }
    function ConfirmReject() {

        return confirm('Are u sure to reject it?');
    }


</script>
<h3>Manage Registration<h3>
@if (TempData["Msg"] != null)
{<h3 @TempData["Msg"].ToString()</h3>
}
<h4>@if (ViewBag.Status == "P")
    {<b>@Html.ActionLink("Pending Requests", "Index", new { Status = "P" })</b>
    }
    else
    {

        @Html.ActionLink("Pending Requests", "Index", new { Status = "P" })
    }
        @if (ViewBag.Status == "A")
        {
            <b>@Html.ActionLink("Approved Requests", "Index", new { Status = "A" })</b>
        }
        else
        {

            @Html.ActionLink("Approved Requests", "Index", new { Status = "A" })
        }
    @if (ViewBag.Status == "R")
    {
        <b>@Html.ActionLink("Rejected Requests", "Index", new { Status = "R" })</b>
    }
    else
    {

        @Html.ActionLink("Rejected Requests", "Index", new { Status = "R" })
    }

</h4
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Approve/Reject</th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First_Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Last_Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Department_Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Team_Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Select_Members)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Approved)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email_ID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Competition.CategoryName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approve", new { id = item.Registration_ID }, new { onclick = "return ConfirmApprove();" }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Reject", "Reject", new { id = item.Registration_ID }, new { onclick = "return ConfirmReject();" })

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.First_Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Last_Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department_Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Team_Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Select_Members)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Approved)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email_ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Competition.CategoryName)
        </td>
    </tr> }
</table>
**Admin Base Contoller**

    public class BaseAdminController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Admin/BaseAdmin

        protected AdminBs objBs;
        public BaseAdminController()
    {
        objBs = new AdminBs();
    }
    }
```

**registerbs class that is used in approval controller**

```
 public class RegisterBs
    {
    private  RegisterDb objDb;

        public RegisterBs()
        {

            objDb = new RegisterDb();
        }
        public IEnumerable<Registration> GetALL()
        {

            return objDb.GetALL();

        }
        public Registration GetByID(int Id)
        {
            return objDb.GetByID(Id);

        }
        public void Insert(Registration registration)
        {
            objDb.Insert(registration);


        }
        public void Delete(int Id)
        {
            objDb.Delete(Id);

        }
        public void Update(Registration registration)
        {
            objDb.Update(registration);

        }

    }
<b>Registration db class<b>

     public class RegisterDb
    {

        private XtechContext db;

        public RegisterDb()
        {

            db= new XtechContext();
        }
      public IEnumerable<Registration> GetALL()
        {

            return db.Registrations.ToList(); 

    }
        public Registration GetByID(int Id)
      {
          return db.Registrations.Find(Id);

      }
        public void Insert(Registration registration)
        {
            db.Registrations.Add(registration);
            Save();

        }
       public void Delete(int Id)
        {
            Registration registration = db.Registrations.Find(Id);
            db.Registrations.Remove(registration);
            Save();

        }
       public void Update(Registration registration)
        {
            db.Entry(registration).State = EntityState.Modified;

        }
        public void Save()
       {
           db.SaveChanges();
       }
    }
```

[this is the interface pic then you easily understand it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybBRH.png)

Comment: Not clear what you actual question is, but you have an `Index(string Status)` method and neither your `Approve()` or `Reject()` methods pass a value for` Status` when they redirect to the `Index()` method

Comment: Could you add the implementation of `RegisterDb.Update` ?

Comment: yes    public void Update(Registration registration)
        {
            db.Entry(registration).State = EntityState.Modified;

        }

Comment: i Re Edit my post , and also upload the picture of UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not call `SaveChanges` on the context that why your modifications are not persisted to the database.

You may add a call to `Save()` in your update method.